# Как отправить файл на сторонний сервер

Tags: php, curl

Необходимо отправить файл на сторонний сервер но получаю ошибку. делаю так:

```
/*Array
(
    [imgfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => TB2wRxQcSvHfKJjSZFPXXbttpXa_!!2369743095.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phph4FX05
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 32856
        )

)*/

    $tmpfile = $_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = basename($_FILES['imgfile']['name']);
    $data = array(
        'imgcode' => '@'.$tmpfile.';filename='.$filename,
    );
    $curl = curl_init();   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://h5api.t-b.ru.com/taobao/upload_img');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    //$out = json_decode($out);
    curl_close($curl);
    print_r($out);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я не так делаю?

Comment: Ошибка секретная какая-то, да?

Comment: @u_mulder я не понимаю в чем проблема, может вы знаете?

Comment: @newProgrammer Зачем вы упорно вставляете ссылку на сторонний сайт? Она не имеет отношения к сути вопроса.

Comment: @newProgrammer Дак ошибку то покажите)

Comment: @robertobadjio исправил извиняюсь

Comment: То что в картинке - это ответ стороннего сервера или вашего скрипта?

Comment: @hindmost ответ от стороннего сервера, я по этому ссылку вставил чтобы понят как сам сайт отправляет файл.

Comment: Лично у меня нет никакого желания лезть на этот сайт чтобы что-то там понять. Но из того что я вижу сейчас, могу только посоветовать отключить проверку SSL сертификата, т.к. сторонний сервер на https.